# mybatis sqlSession().selectmap returns Map<key,Map<key,value>> instead Map<ky,value>

Tags: mybatis

Recently we have upgraded from ibatis to mybatis.

We were using ibatis queryformap method to return a Map object.
Since it upgraded to mybatis we are using the releavant function selectmap.
But it returns `Map<key,Map<key,value>>`  instead `Map<ky,value>`. 
My Code.

DAO.java

```
public Map<String, Date> getCoverageDateList(Long personId,
        Date coverageEffectiveDate) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("personId", personId);
    map.put("coverageEffectiveDate", coverageEffectiveDate);


    return getDataAccessTemplate().selectMap("Quote.getCoverageDateList", map, "productType");

}
```

Quote.xml

```
<select id="getCoverageDateList" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultMap="coverageMap">

SELECT
distinct 
    ql.productType
    ,q.coverageEffectiveDate as coverageDate
FROM Coverage cv inner join Quote q on q.quoteId = cv.quoteid
inner join  Quoteline ql on ql.lineid=cv.quotelineId
where
(cv.customerpersonid = #{personId} or cv.customerpersonid = @personId)
and (#{coverageEffectiveDate} between cv.rateEffectivedate and cv.rateTerminationDate)
</select>

    <resultMap id="coverageMap" type="java.util.HashMap">
    <result property="productType" column="productType"/>
    <result property="coverageDate" column="coverageDate"/>
</resultMap>
```

Could anyone please help.